# "obvious" shift/reduce error in 6 tokens or less

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a grammar, illustrated below, in which statements have an error clause that can include an arbitrary number of statements.  The error clause must be terminated by an END (like case/esac in the shell).  In the absence of an error clause, the statement *may* be terminated, but need not be.

The bison report shows 2 s/r conflicts.  In each case, the conflict is about what to do with the terminator, either:

- shift, and go to the state that only reduces it, or
- reduce it

That seems like a distinction without a difference to me, but I haven't been able to explain that to bison.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic.  I'm hoping someone can explain what it is.

```
%token ERROR ARG

%right WALK RUN
%left  KLAW NUR 
                        
%%

statements:     statement
        |       statements statement
                ;

statement:      walk
        |       run
                ;

args:           ARG
        |       args ARG
                ;

on_error:       ERROR statements
                ;

walk:           WALK ARG args on_error KLAW
        |       WALK ARG args
        |       WALK ARG args          KLAW 
                ;

run:            RUN ARG args on_error NUR
        |       RUN ARG args          nur
                ;

nur:            %empty
        |       NUR
        ;
```

Here's part of the report I'm looking at:

```
State 12

    6 args: args . ARG
    8 walk: WALK ARG args . on_error KLAW
    9     | WALK ARG args .
   10     | WALK ARG args . KLAW

    ERROR  shift, and go to state 14
    ARG    shift, and go to state 15
    KLAW   shift, and go to state 16

    KLAW      [reduce using rule 9 (walk)]
    $default  reduce using rule 9 (walk)

    on_error  go to state 17
...
State 16

   10 walk: WALK ARG args KLAW .

    $default  reduce using rule 10 (walk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following short program (six tokens, but I cheated by leaving out the ARGs, because they are just clutter. You can pretend that every WALK is followed by at least two ARGs, but it makes no difference to the problem. I also subscripted the WALKs for clarity)

```
WALK-1 ERROR WALK-2 KLAW WALK-3 KLAW
```

What does it mean? The options are (with KLAWs numbered to match their WALK):

```
    WALK-1
      ERROR WALK-2
    KLAW-1
    WALK-3 KLAW-3
```

or

```
    WALK-1
      ERROR WALK-2 KLAW-2
            WALK-3
    KLAW-1
```

I guess those have different semantics; in the first one `WALK-3` always runs after `WALK-1` while in the second one it only runs if there was an error in `WALK-1`.

---

It's possible that you are misreading the state table Bison presents you with. In State 12, the conflicting options are to reduce using production 9 (`walk: WALK ARG args`) leaving `KLAW` to match some other `WALK`, or to shift `KLAW` and then reduce using production 10 (`walk: WALK ARG args KLAW`), which means that `KLAW` matches *this* `WALK`.

---

It's also possible that you are left wondering why your precedence declarations had no effect.

Precedence rules are used to resolve conflicts, such as that in State 12, where a lookahead token might either be shifted or retained until after one or more reductions. The resolution is to compare the precedence of the lookahead token (`KLAW` in this case) with the precedence of the production which could be reduced (`walk: WALK ARG args`). If the lookahead token has higher precedence, then the lookahead token is shifted; if the production has higher precedence, then the production is reduced. If they have the same precedence, then associativity is applied (reduce for `%left`; shift for `%right`).

That's fine, but how does Bison compute the precedence of `walk: WALK ARG args`? The simple answer is that Bison uses the precedence of the **last** terminal in the production, in this case `ARG`. But `ARG` doesn't have a declared precedence, so the production's precedence is unspecified, and precedence resolution only applies if both the rule and the token have defined precedence.

In order for precedence resolution to help, you would have to either:

- Add `ARG` to your precedence declarations, or
- use `%prec` (q.v.) to associate the production with a different terminal symbol.

Comment: Its even more complex -- if you remove the last `KLAW` in this example, then the first parse is still legal (WALK-3 has no ERROR block, so the KLAW is "optional"), but the second is not (WALK-1 must have a KLAW due to the ERROR).  You don't know whether that final claw exists or not when resolving the conflict (only 1 token lookahead), so if your precedence rules decide to shift (binding the KLAW to the nearest WALK, which one might think is the most reasonable), you'll end up with a syntax error if the final KLAW is not there.

Comment: @chris: that's true. I should have mentioned it in my discussion of precedence; I didn't mean to imply that precedence could solve the ambiguity but rereading it, it does come off that way. I'll try to rewrite it.

Comment: @rici, I wish I could do more than just thank you.  Your assessment of my confusion was right on both counts: I hadn't quite digested the state table, and I didn't understand how precedence is applied.  I'm glad I found a way to present the problem, and that you took the time to craft such a clear answer.